# SQL data export: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. (System.Data)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am trying to export my database as .Net SqlClient Data Provider format but I keep getting this error message
The operation could not be completed
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. (System.Data)

Program Location:
code:

```
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
       at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.DTSWizard.GetOpenedConnection(WizardInputs wizardInputs, String connEntryName)
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.Step2.OnLeavePage(LeavePageEventArgs e)


    but my app config has the connection string declared as

code:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <configSections>
        </configSections>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="WindowsApplication2.My.MySettings.ConnectionString"
                connectionString="Data Source=ARULJUSTIN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=firemaintain;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
                providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        </connectionStrings>
        <startup>
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
        </startup>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="data  source=ARULJUSTIN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=firemaintain;Integrated  Security=True;Pooling=False" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and to access it try using

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString
```